# static functions constant static member functions

Tags: c++, static, constants

I want to ask a simple question

Like for example in my private member I have declared static member.

```
static int id;
```

and in the public I have used getter function for this id

```
static int getID() const;
```

The compilor is giving me an error but when I dont use const it does not give any error, because this is only getter it should be constant, please tell me the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `static` function which cannot be `const`, because it doesn't act on any particular instance of class. This means such function has no `this` pointer (passed implicitly as hidden argument) to any particular instance. You should write

```
static int id;
static int getID();
```

It is also possible to make this function non `static`

```
int getID() const;
```

however such a function in general should be static, as long as it doesn't need access to specific object's representation.